# Embedding version number VS efficient caching using HTTP headers

Tags: caching, http-headers, httpresponse, server, http-caching

I found that we can use http headers like:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=86400
Etag: "asdfasdfasdfa"
```

to ensure that a resource is cached and is not fetched again from server if file at server is not changed.
The server sends 304 response if file is not changed and 200 as response if file is changed.

This serves whole purpose, then why it is recommended to embed a fingerprint of the file, or a version number, in its filename - e.g. `style.x234dff.css` to ensure that if there is some change at the resource at the server latest files are served

Comment: Can you also put a link to the document/page that recommends that a version number to be added to the file name?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching#cache-control

Answer (score 0):

It provides a nice pattern to achieve maximum efficiency while retrieving the latest files when needed. For example, let's take a following example.

[image]

So for the stylesheet /style.3da37df.css, the intermediate caches and the browser will receive a response like

```
200 OK
Content-Length: 1024
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
Etag: x234dff
```

So the caches/browser interpret the response as for the same URL they can use a local copy for a year since now. So for the same URL, they don't even have to do request to see if the etag has changed.

> For example, in above exchange the server returns a 1024 byte
>   response, instructs the client to cache it for up to 1 year, and
>   provides a validation token (“x234dff”) that can be used ***after the
>   response has expired*** to check if the resource has been modified.

So the etag if to be used when the response is expired. So for the next year they can safely use the local copy without any checks. However, it might be be required to force the intermediate caches and browsers to force the style to be fetched again. This can be done by adding a  fingerprint in the filename because whenever the URL is changed (it will because of the name change), the resource is fetched again. Because the main page says Cachec-control: no-cache i.e. not to cache the main page, these URL changes in the HTML source are always detected by the browser.

> So, how do we get the best of both worlds: client-side caching and
>   quick updates? Simple, we can change the URL of the resource and force
>   the user to download the new response whenever its content changes.
>   Typically, this is done by embedding a fingerprint of the file, or a
>   version number, in its filename - e.g. style.x234dff.css.
>
> The combination of ETag, Cache-Control, and unique URLs allows us to
>   deliver the best of all worlds: long-lived expiry times, control over
>   where the response can be cached, and on-demand updates.